# Python : How to handle multiple clients and a server

Tags: python, sockets, client

I am implementing a program with a server and multiple clients. All clients send data to the server and a server check out the step of each client. If all client's steps are the same, a server sends new data to all clients to do next step. And it continues this procedure again and again.

However, when I run my program, it cannot communicate each other. Here are my code. Would you give me some hints?

**client & server**

```
#client
from socket import *
from sys import *
import time
import stat, os
import glob

# set the socket parameters
host = "localhost"
port = 21567
buf = 1024
data = ''
addr = (host, port)

UDPSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
UDPSock.settimeout(100)

def_msg = "=== TEST ==="

#FILE = open("test.jpg", "w+")
FILE = open("data.txt","w+")

while (1):
  #data, addr = UDPSock.recvfrom(buf)
  print "Sending"
  UDPSock.sendto(def_msg, addr)
  #time.sleep(3)
  data, addr = UDPSock.recvfrom(buf)

  if data == 'done':
   FILE.close()
   break
  FILE.write(data)

  print "Receiving"
  #time.sleep(3)

UDPSock.close()

# server program for nvt

from socket import *
import os, sys, time, glob
#import pygame
import stat

host = 'localhost'
port = 21567
buf = 1024
addr = (host, port)

print 'test server'

UDPSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
UDPSock.bind(addr)

msg = "send txt file to all clients"

#FILE = open("cam.jpg", "r+")
FILE = open("dna.dat","r+")
sending_data = FILE.read()
FILE.close()

tmp_data = sending_data

while (1):
  #UDPSock.listen(1)
  #UDPSock.sendto(msg, addr)
  #FILE = open("gen1000.dat","r+")
  #sending_data = FILE.read()
  #FILE.close()


  #print 'client is at', addr
  data, addr = UDPSock.recvfrom(buf)
  #time.sleep(3)
  print data
  #msg = 'hello'

  # 
  tmp, sending_data = sending_data[:buf-6], sending_data[buf-6:]

  if len(tmp) < 1:
    msg = 'done'
    UDPSock.sendto(msg, addr)
    print "finished"
    sending_data = tmp_data

  UDPSock.sendto(tmp, addr)
  print "sending"
  #time.sleep(3)
UDPSock.close()
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use UDP? I hope you know what UDP is and how it works: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol

Answer (score 1):

A server must perform the sequence `socket()`, `bind()`, `listen()`, `accept()` (possibly repeating the `accept()` to service more than one client), while a client only needs the sequence `socket()`, `connect()`.

Your missing `listen()` i saw first. Listen for connections made to the socket.

More on this here: [link text](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.listen)

Answer (score 1):

Look at this: http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/Python/PyNet.pdf

It's a very good Python networking tutorial including working examples of a client and server.  Now, I'm not an expert on this, but it looks to me like your code is overcomplicated.  And what's the deal with all the commented-out lines?

*Quote from question:*

```
#UDPSock.listen(1)
#UDPSock.sendto(msg, addr)
#FILE = open("gen1000.dat","r+")
#sending_data = FILE.read()
#FILE.close()
```

*End quote*

Those look like some pretty important lines to me.

Also, make sure the computers are connected.  From a prompt run:

```
ping [IP]
```

where `[IP]` is the IP address of the other machine(Note: if you're not connected to the same LAN, this becomes much harder as you *might* then need port forwarding and **possibly** static IPs).

Comment: The document referenced on this answer is no longer available. Apart from that the rest of the answer seems more like a comment than an answer.